# Altera DE0-nano. Struggling to make a SPI slave device

Tags: process, spi

I'm new to VHDL and I thought I could try to make a slave SPI device as training, but it's not working quite as expected. Below my current code. It's compiles and upload just fine, but it's not working as intended. Right now I have the leds connected to the signal "bitnumber", bitnumber is supposed to increment on each rising edge of CLK and then reset to zero when the SS pin is pulled LOW (indicating that the transfer is complete), but it doesn't do that. I've connected my Altera DE0-nano to my arduino which is simply pulling the SS LOW, sends four clock pulses and then pulls the SS back high, I've put a 1s delay between each transition. The leds on my altera board does change it's pattern every second, but it does so on both rising and falling edge of the clock, also the led pattern seems completely random, even showing some leds in a dimmed state. The leds become black when the SS pin goes back HIGH though, that's good.

```
enter code here
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity SPI2 is
PORT (LED : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
                GPIO_0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
end SPI2;
architecture SPI2_beh of SPI2 is
signal SPIdataregister : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
signal bitnumber : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
begin
LED <= bitnumber;
        process(GPIO_0(5), GPIO_0(3))
        begin
                if ((GPIO_0(5)) = '1') then
                        bitnumber <= (bitnumber + '1');
                end if;
                if ((GPIO_0(3)) = '1') then
                        bitnumber <= "00000000";               
                end if;
        end process;
        process(bitnumber)
        begin
                case bitnumber is
                        when "00000001" => SPIdataregister(0) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000010" => SPIdataregister(1) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000011" => SPIdataregister(2) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000100" => SPIdataregister(3) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000101" => SPIdataregister(4) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000110" => SPIdataregister(5) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00000111" => SPIdataregister(6) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when "00001000" => SPIdataregister(7) <= GPIO_0(7);
                        when others => SPIdataregister <= SPIdataregister;
                end case;
        end process;
end SPI2_beh;
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the main process to:

```
    process(GPIO_0(5), GPIO_0(3))
            variable change_flag : STD_LOGIC := 1;
    begin
            if GPIO_0(3) = '1' then
                    bitnumber <= "00000000";   
            else 
                    if GPIO_0(5) = '0' --btw here, GPIO_0(3) = '0' also
                            change_flag := '1';
                    else --btw here, GPIO_0(3) = '0' and GPIO_0(5) = '1'
                            if change_flag = '1' then
                                    bitnumber <= bitnumber + 1;
                                    change_flag := '0';
                            end if;
                    end if;
            end if;
    end process;
```

The variable change_flag introduces memory, to ensure the process only reacts once to specifically a rising edge of GPIO_0(5). Without memory implemented like this, you could get the desired effect by having two processes: one dependent on GPIO_0(5) and one dependent on GPIO_0(3). The risk then is of both changing at the same time and causing a conflict: two signals trying to control/change the same output. The above way is better and should be reliable for your purposes.

Secondly, increment bitnumber using 
                        bitnumber <= bitnumber + 1; 
note, use the 1 without the quotes. The quotes indicate binary '1' and '0' from what I understand.

Good luck!!